# Computing the standard deviation of a Number array in Java

Tags: java, statistics

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/computing-the-standard-deviation-of-a-number-array-in-java-follow-up).)

I have this funky class method for computing standard deviation from an array of `Number` objects using the Stream API:

**StandardDeviation.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class StandardDeviation {

    public static double computeStandardDeviation(Number... collection) {
        if (collection.length == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }

        final double average =
                Arrays.stream(collection)
                      .mapToDouble((x) -> x.doubleValue())
                      .summaryStatistics()
                      .getAverage();

        final double rawSum = 
                Arrays.stream(collection)
                      .mapToDouble((x) -> Math.pow(x.doubleValue() - average,
                                                   2.0))
                      .sum();

        return Math.sqrt(rawSum / (collection.length - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Mix 'em all!
        double sd = computeStandardDeviation((byte) 1, 
                                             (short) 2, 
                                             3, 
                                             4L, 
                                             5.0f, 
                                             6.0);

        System.out.println(sd);
    }
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a nice and clean, short piece of code. :) It also appears to calculate the result correctly. My observations will follow, but really, only the first one is actually an issue:

- The application will crash with a `NullPointerException` if you try to compute the standard deviation for `null`. In addition to checking `collection.length == 0`, you should first check for `collection == null`.
- You should be consistent with your use of the `final` modifier. Finalize that `Number... collection`, `String[] args` and `double sd` too.
- While at it, you could finalize the entire class as well and add an empty private constructor: `private StandardDeviation() { /* prevent instantiation */ }`. It's an utility class with only static methods, so you don't need anyone calling `new StandardDeviation()` as it currently stands. Some static code analyzers would actually point this out as a minor issue for you.
- Personally I find the use of method references nice and clear, so you could replace `.mapToDouble((x) -> x.doubleValue())` with `.mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)`
- I find that `.mapToDouble((x) -> Math.pow(x.doubleValue() - average, 2.0))` does too much at once, you could also do it like this instead: `.mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).map(x -> x - average).map(StandardDeviation::square)` and then you'd have a new method like this in your class: `private static Double square(final Double value) { return Math.pow(value, 2.0); }`. At least the Math.pow(...) part is much easier to read as a method reference.
- As an external user of your utility class I'd like the option to call the standard deviation method with a `Collection` instead of varargs parameters. You'd then have to make one of the methods to call the other, first converting either the array into a collection or the other way around. Personally I prefer working with Collections.

Answer (score 6):

- You are traversing the collection twice to determine the standard deviation when you could do it in a single pass.
- Also, you could accumulate quickly rounding errors with the `Math.pow(x.doubleValue() - average, 2.0)` call. It would be best to implement the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) (that the Stream API has for `DoubleStream#sum()`).
- In the lambda expression `(x) -> x.doubleValue()`, you don't need to add the parentheses around `(x)`. You can just have `x -> x.doubleValue()`. You could also use a method-reference, which avoids a lamda, and have `Number::doubleValue`.

On Stack Overflow, I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36264148/1743880) which calculates the standard deviation in a single pass with compensation. It is parallel-friendly:

```
static class DoubleStatistics extends DoubleSummaryStatistics {

    private double sumOfSquare = 0.0d;
    private double sumOfSquareCompensation; // Low order bits of sum
    private double simpleSumOfSquare; // Used to compute right sum for
                                        // non-finite inputs

    @Override
    public void accept(double value) {
        super.accept(value);
        double squareValue = value * value;
        simpleSumOfSquare += squareValue;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(squareValue);
    }

    public DoubleStatistics combine(DoubleStatistics other) {
        super.combine(other);
        simpleSumOfSquare += other.simpleSumOfSquare;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquare);
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquareCompensation);
        return this;
    }

    private void sumOfSquareWithCompensation(double value) {
        double tmp = value - sumOfSquareCompensation;
        double velvel = sumOfSquare + tmp; // Little wolf of rounding error
        sumOfSquareCompensation = (velvel - sumOfSquare) - tmp;
        sumOfSquare = velvel;
    }

    public double getSumOfSquare() {
        double tmp = sumOfSquare + sumOfSquareCompensation;
        if (Double.isNaN(tmp) && Double.isInfinite(simpleSumOfSquare)) {
            return simpleSumOfSquare;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public final double getStandardDeviation() {
        long count = getCount();
        double sumOfSquare = getSumOfSquare();
        double average = getAverage();
        return count > 0 ? Math.sqrt((sumOfSquare - count * Math.pow(average, 2)) / (count - 1)) : 0.0d;
    }

    public static Collector<Double, ?, DoubleStatistics> collector() {
        return Collector.of(DoubleStatistics::new, DoubleStatistics::accept, DoubleStatistics::combine);
    }

}
```

It has the same logic as [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) but extended to calculate the sum of squares.

With such a class, you can then have:

```
public static double computeStandardDeviation(Number... collection) {
    return Arrays.stream(collection)
                 .map(Number::doubleValue)
                 .collect(DoubleStatistics.collector())
                 .getStandardDeviation();
}
```

Comment: You are very knowledgeable about Java's APIs.

Comment: This version calculates the standard deviation as 

count > 0 ? Math.sqrt((sumOfSquare - count * Math.pow(average, 2)) / (count - 1)) : 0.0d;

but the version you link to on StackOverflows has

getCount() > 0 ? Math.sqrt((getSumOfSquare() / getCount()) - Math.pow(getAverage(), 2)) : 0.0d;

Are they equivalent?