# Computing the standard deviation of a Number array in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, statistics

(See the [first and initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125409/computing-the-standard-deviation-of-a-number-array-in-java).)

Now I make only one pass over the data in order to compute the standard deviation of the input `Number`s, and that's how:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i^2 - 2\mu x_i + \mu^2) \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n \mu^2 \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2 \Bigg( \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n} \Bigg) \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n \Bigg( \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n} \Bigg)^2 \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2 \Bigg( \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n} \Bigg) \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + \frac{1}{n}\Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg)^2 \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{2}{n} \Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg) \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + \frac{1}{n}\Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg)^2 \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{2}{n} \Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg)^2 + \frac{1}{n}\Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg)^2 \\
                             &= \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n} \Bigg( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \Bigg)^2.
\end{align}

My code is as follows:

**StandardDeviation.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public final class StandardDeviation {

    public static double computeStandardDeviation(final Number... array) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array, "The input number array is null.");

        if (array.length == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }

        MyConsumer myConsumer = new MyConsumer();

        Arrays.stream(array)
              .map(Number::doubleValue)
              .forEach(myConsumer);

        int n = array.length;
        double sum = myConsumer.getSum();
        double sumOfSquares = myConsumer.getSumOfSquares();
        double intermediate = sumOfSquares - sum * sum / n;

        return Math.sqrt(intermediate / (n - 1));
    }

    public static double
            computeStandardDeviation(final Collection<Number> collection) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(collection,
                               "The input number collection is null");
        return computeStandardDeviation(
                collection.toArray(new Number[collection.size()]));
    }

    private StandardDeviation() {}

    private static final class MyConsumer implements Consumer<Double> {

        private double sum;
        private double sumOfSquares;

        @Override
        public void accept(Double t) {
            sum += t;
            sumOfSquares += t * t;
        }

        double getSum() {
            return sum;
        }

        double getSumOfSquares() {
            return sumOfSquares;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Mix 'em all!
        double sd = computeStandardDeviation(Arrays.asList((byte) 1,
                                                           (short) 2,
                                                           3,
                                                           4L,
                                                           5.0f,
                                                           6.0));
        System.out.println(sd);
    }
}
```

Any critique much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### Boxing

Your current class `MyConsumer` implements `Consumer<Double>`. This means that every time an element is accepted, it will unboxed into a `double`.

```
@Override
public void accept(Double t) {
    sum += t;  // <-- unboxed into double
    sumOfSquares += t * t;   // <-- here also
}
```

On large datasets, this can have a huge performance impact. Instead, it would be preferable to implement the primitive [`DoubleConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleConsumer.html) interface, and thus change your `accept` method into

```
@Override
public void accept(double t) {
    // ...
}
```

This way, there won't be any overhead involving autoboxing.

This will also involve a change inside your main method. You will need to use `mapToDouble` instead of `map`.

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
```

This is also a good change to do: currently, each `Number` would be converted to a `double`, only to be boxed into a `Double` by `map`, then `unboxed` multiple times inside the consumer.

#### `collect` instead of `forEach`

You aren't using properly the Stream API in your main pipeline:

```
MyConsumer myConsumer = new MyConsumer();

Arrays.stream(array)
      .map(Number::doubleValue)
      .forEach(myConsumer);
```

The problem with this code is that it mixed both the functional approach of the Stream API with the traditional iterative `forEach`. This can generally break in multiple ways when you're using a parallel pipeline.

The Stream API was designed so that parallel capabilities can be introduced effectively. The case of `forEach` is even mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> A small number of stream operations, such as `forEach()` and `peek()`, can operate only via side-effects; these should be used with care.
>
>  [...] 
> the `forEach()` can simply be replaced with a reduction operation that is safer, more efficient, and more amenable to parallelization.

This is what `collect` (and the more general `reduce`) is for.

So let's make that parallel-friendly and take a look at [`collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjDoubleConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method.

- The supplier is a function returning the new result container.
- The accumulator is a function that takes the current result container and the current Stream element and incorporates it into the container.
- The combiner is a function that takes two result containers and merges them into one. This argument is only used in case of a parallel pipeline.

To adhere with that contract, we need to change `MyConsumer`:

1. `MyConsumer` isn't really a consumer anymore, it will be a class responsible for collecting the values into statistics having notably a `sum` and `sumOfSquares`. Let's rename it `StatCollector` (for lack of a better name). It does consume `double` as input so it makes sense to let it implement `DoubleConsumer`.
2. As seen by the above signature, it needs to handle a case of merging two containers, so we need to add a method `public void combine(StatCollector other)` that will be responsible for that.

This is what we end up with:

```
private static final class StatCollector implements DoubleConsumer {

    private double sum;
    private double sumOfSquares;

    @Override
    public void accept(double t) {
        sum += t;
        sumOfSquares += t * t;
    }
    
    public void combine(StatCollector other) {
        sum += other.sum;
        sumOfSquares += other.sumOfSquares;
    }

    double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    double getSumOfSquares() {
        return sumOfSquares;
    }
}
```

used with

```
StatCollector stat = 
    Arrays.stream(array)
          .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
          .collect(StatCollector::new, StatCollector::accept, StatCollector::combine);
```